# ReactJS dynamically get products by category from database

Tags: reactjs

I retrieve the categories from the database. Retrieving the information from my API. When clicking on a category it needs to show all the products in that category retrieved from my API.[Menu page showing all categories.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9YJE.png)

I tried with onclicks but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you should add an onClick callBack that will fetch the products of the clicked category,

```
getProducts(id){
    // your Logic, api call, update state ...
}

<Card onClick={ id => getProducts(categories.id)} ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want see all products when you click Card component? If you try put onClick in a own homemade component it doesn't work. Only fires event in plain html components. I dunno how is your Card component but I'll show this suggestion...

```js
class Card {

  (...)

  render(){
    return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>{...}</div>
  }

}
```

```js
class Menu {

  (...)

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <Card onClick={() => getProducts(category.id)} ...
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Other solution is wrapping a div on Card component that fires onClick

```js
class Menu {

  (...)

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <div onClick={() => getProducts(category.id)}>
          <Card...
        </div>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey! The idea is that when I click on a certain category I only get all the products from that catergory. So my idea was to filter this true an id. But I don't know how to do it